# How to stop dailymotion player

Tags: dailymotion-api

There is the possibility to pause dailymotion player.

```
player.pause();
```

How to move the player to the start screen making the event PLAYER_START when the user click it.

The most close solution I found is to seek to the end of the video.

```
prevvd = state.videoDuration;
player.seek(prevvd);
```

But in that case the player is in replay screen.

Comment: Your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77991157/14732669) 's close reason is not resolved. You need to provide [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) to illustrate details.